# How to let dependencies in modules have higher precedence over build.gradle in the top level repository

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

My project repository tree looks like the following:

```
Project
  module1
    module1.gradle
  module2
    module2.gradle
  ...
  build.gradle
```

Then in the `build.gradle` file there are some dependencies and some forced resolutionStrategies like

```
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        force 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.5.0-cdh5.3.3',
      }
  }
  dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.6.0-cdh5.16.1')
  }
```

However, `module1.gradle` defines a later version of hadoop-common like

```
compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.5.0-cdh5.3.3'
```

I want to make this upgrade to my module1, module2..moduleX to use the '2.6.0-cdh5.16.1'. There are some projects that don't need the upgrade and should keep using the older version so I need to keep the forced dependencies in the top level `build.gradle` file. In fact, I don't want to touch any modules that I don't own.

Is there a way to specify at the module level to ALWAYS use whatever it is defined in the current module instead of inheriting from the top level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:module_replacement

Comment: Can you clarify- is the code snipped from `build.gradle` being applied to `allprojects { .. }`? (or subprojects, that is equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force(..)` statement at the top level is intended to override whatever version is specified in the modules.

You can re-override that `force(..)` statement by placing another `force(..)` statement inside the module build. This second `force` statement is evaluated after the top-level one, so it will re-override the module version.

You can place in the `build.gradle` file for your module:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.0-cdh5.16.1'
  }
}
```

---

Note though that overriding and re-overriding versions can cause confusion. In example, people editing the top-level build will expect their `force` to be rightly applied to all modules- which isn't the case if you re-override that in the module.